# PHP check if user is an admin/user and display buttons

Tags: php, button, hide, admin, display

I'm not a pro in PHP so need a little help.

I have a log in function on my website which checks if user is an admin or a normal user which works perfectly fine.

I'm adding a new functionality where the system should check if user is logged in and display different buttons.

- If user is not logged in then display sign in/sign up buttons.
- If user is logged in as a user then display user.php button and
     logout.php
- If user is an admin then display admin.php and logout.php

However, it only works for a user. What am I missing? `UserTypeID` is set up 1 for a user and 2 for an admin in the database.

```
session_start();
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['UserTypeID']) == 1) //check if user is a user and display buttons
{
?>
    <li><a href="user.php">My Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>

<?php } elseif(isset($_SESSION['UserTypeID']) == 2) //check if user is an admin and display buttons
{
?>
    <li><a href="admin.php">My Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>

<?php  }else{ // if user is not logged in then display these buttons?> 
    <li><a href="signin.php">Sign In</a></li>
    <li><a href="signup.php">Sign Up</a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: isset($_SESSION['UserTypeID']) is 0 or 1, never 2.

Comment: `session_start();` is outside of `<?php` ?

Comment: Hi Gerard, in my database admin is set up as 2 and it works fine for logging in . Don't think that's an issue

Comment: Hi kerbholz, yeah i realised that. but it doesn't fix the issue. something else is missing. thanks

Comment: @DawidOskwarek what you need to check is $_SESSION['UserTypeID'] == 2, without the isset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isset($_SESSION['UserTypeID'])` returns `true` or `false`

```
session_start();
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['UserTypeID']) && $_SESSION['UserTypeID']== 1) //check if user is a user and display buttons
    {
    ?>
    <li><a href="user.php">My Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>

    <?php } elseif(isset($_SESSION['UserTypeID']) && $_SESSION['UserTypeID'] == 2) //check if user is an admin and display buttons
    {
    ?>
    <li><a href="admin.php">My Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>


<?php  }else{ // if user is not logged in then display these buttons?> 
<li><a href="signin.php">Sign In</a></li>
<li><a href="signup.php">Sign Up</a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: @DawidOskwarek Don't forget to accept it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Do Something like this.This will works.

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(!empty($_SESSION['UserTypeID']) && $_SESSION['UserTypeID']== 1) //check if user is a user and display buttons
{
?>
<li><a href="user.php">My Account</a></li>
<li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>

<?php } else if(!empty($_SESSION['UserTypeID']) && $_SESSION['UserTypeID']== 2) //check if user is an admin and display buttons
{
?>
<li><a href="admin.php">My Account</a></li>
<li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>

<?php  }else{ // if user is not logged in then display these buttons?> 
<li><a href="signin.php">Sign In</a></li>
<li><a href="signup.php">Sign Up</a></li>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

**session_start()  function need to write inside php and write coding as below :**

```
  <?php 
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['UserTypeID']) && $_SESSION['UserTypeID']== 1) //check if user is a user and display buttons
     {
     ?>
   <li><a href="user.php">My Account</a></li>
   <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>

  <?php } elseif(isset($_SESSION['UserTypeID']) && $_SESSION['UserTypeID'] == 2) //check if user is an admin and display buttons
       {
      ?>
     <li><a href="admin.php">My Account</a></li>
   <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>


   <?php  }else{ // if user is not logged in then display these buttons?> 
  <li><a href="signin.php">Sign In</a></li>
  <li><a href="signup.php">Sign Up</a></li>
 <?php } ?>
```